# Pandas. Как лучше добавлять новый столбец со значением в существующий DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Вот пример, моделирующий ситуацию с предупреждением:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": ["a", "b", "a"]})

...    # do something

df1 = df[df.col2 == "a"]

df1["new_column"], df1["case"] = np.nan, ""
```

Этот вполне безобидный код делает то что нужно, и это подтверждается выводом в консоли:

```
df1
Out[16]: 
   col1 col2  new_column case
0     1    a         NaN     
2     3    a         NaN     

df
Out[17]: 
   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    a
```

Однако вылетеает забавное предупреждение, которое пугает своей непонятностью:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df1["new_column"], df1["case"] = np.nan, ""
```

Которое рекомендует делать что то по другому.
Два вопроса:

- *Почему то как я добавляю столбец - это плохо, судя по предупреждению*
- *Как мне лучше добавлять столбец с заданным значением*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не смотря на то, что ошибка индицирует вот эту строку:

```
df1["new_column"], df1["case"] = np.nan, ""
```

корень проблемы у вас вот в этой строке:

```
df1 = df[df.col2 == "a"]
```

здесь вы создаете `ссылку` на срез датафрейма df. О чем вас и предупреждают. От вас требуется эксплицитно указать, работаете ли вы с ссылкой (view) или копией (copy). В вашем случае, одним из решений может быть явное создание копии df:

```
df1 = df[df.col2 == "a"].copy()
```

Comment: если бы я создал ссылку, как вы говорите, то при добавлении к ней столбцов, столбцы добавились бы и исходному фрейму ?   Но этого не произошло.
Я видимо не понимаю в чем таки проблема  -  прощу, вам не сложно привести короткий код, чтобы пояснить возможную проблему?
Код ведь работает правильно.
Видимо я разложил грабли, но еще не наступил на них.  Прошу - показать "эксплицитно", где эти грабли )

Comment: Так pandas сделала работу за вас. Она имплицитно создала копию исходного фрейма, и поэтому выдала вам не ошибку, а предупреждение.

Comment: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: мне больше понравилось [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).
Мож кому пригодится )

Comment: Ну это не совсем ваш случай - у вас помимо цепных операций еще и присваивание ссылки на срез.